# Integrate over a region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

I am trying to calculate a integral over a region defined by

[image]

But I dont really know how to do it, I dont know if I have to work in cartesian coordinates or polar coordinates.

The function that I want to integrate is

$\qquad f(x,y) = x^2+y^2-2ax+ \frac{2b^2ax}{x^2+y^2}-b^2$.

Answer (score 19):

Mathematica makes this fairly simple.  We can define a region

```
region = RegionDifference[Disk[{a, 0}, a], Disk[{0, 0}, b]]
(* BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {Disk[{a, 0}, a], 
  Disk[{0, 0}, b]}] *)
```

You can visualise this quite simply, for specific values of `a` and `b` with the following line

```
Block[{a = 3, b = 1}, Region[region]]
```

and an integrand

```
integrand = x^2 + y^2 - 2 a x + 2 b^2 a x/(x^2 + y^2) - b^2;
```

and simply apply `Integrate`.  I hope you find the result informative!

```
Assuming[0 < b < a, 
 Integrate[integrand, {x, y} ∈ region]]
(* 1/24 (-6 a^2 b Sqrt[4 a^2 - b^2] - 
   21 b^3 Sqrt[4 a^2 - b^2] - 12 a^4 π + 8 b^4 π - 
   48 a^2 b^2 ArcCos[Sqrt[b/a]/Sqrt[2]] + 
   48 b^4 ArcCot[b/Sqrt[4 a^2 - b^2]] - 20 a^4 ArcCsc[(2 a)/b] - 
   4 b^4 ArcSec[(2 a)/b] + 44 a^4 ArcSin[b/(2 a)] + 
   48 a^2 b^2 ArcSin[b/(2 a)] - 
   48 a^2 b^2 ArcSin[Sqrt[b/a]/Sqrt[2]] + 
   96 a^2 b^2 ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 + (4 a^2)/b^2]] - 
   48 b^4 ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 + (4 a^2)/b^2]] - 
   16 b^4 ArcTan[b/Sqrt[4 a^2 - b^2]]) *)
```

Comment: `Assuming[0 < b < a, 
 Integrate[integrand, {x, y} \[Element] region] // FullSimplify]` will provide a much simpler form.

Comment: @BobHanlon shorter, certainly and worth looking at.  But I'm not sure it it would seem simpler and more meaningful to the author (it introduces logs of complex numbers for one thing)

Comment: My version (12) returns `1/24 (-4 (6 a^4 + 12 a^2 b^2 + b^4) ArcSec[(2 a)/b] + 
   b (-6 a^2 Sqrt[4 a^2 - b^2] - 21 b^2 Sqrt[4 a^2 - b^2] + 
      32 b^3 \[Pi] - 
      48 b (-2 a^2 + b^2) ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 + (4 a^2)/b^2]] - 
      64 b^3 ArcTan[b/Sqrt[4 a^2 - b^2]]))` which I have verified is equivalent to your shown result for `0 < b < a`

Comment: @BobHanlon interesting.  I'm using V12 too.  I guess that it's an example of one of the reasons why I'm a little reluctant to recommend `FullSimplify` too blindly.

Comment: I guess we do not need to learn multivariable calculus any more because Mathematica makes this easy to do :)