# Symbolic integration in a region obtained using a boolean combination

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, physics, solidmechanics

[Inertia tensors for non-typical rigid bodies](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277997/inertia-tensors-for-non-typical-rigid-bodies)

[Calculate inertia tensors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62894/calculate-inertia-tensors)

[Integrate over a region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210919/integrate-over-a-region)

I'm trying to calculate the moment of inertia for a complex figure depending on the $r$ parameter.

```
c1 = Cylinder[{{0.5, 0, -1}, {0.5, 0, 1}}, 1/2]
c2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, r]
R = RegionDifference[c1, c2]
(***Inertia Field***)
vars = {x, y, z};
r2 = IdentityMatrix[3] Tr[#] - # &@Outer[Times, vars, vars];
r2 // MatrixForm
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Integration works relatively well (except for computational speed) with simple figures and figures specified parametrically. But with boolean combinations, we get such a strange integral that cannot be taken.

```
Integrate[y^2 + z^2, vars \[Element] R, Assumptions -> {r > 0}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Is there any way to get around the problem?

*Version: 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)*

**AFTER SOME TIME:**

In this algorithm, the limits of integration are searched for a simpler region (cylinder), and then the triple integral is calculated. Is it possible to build an efficient computational procedure on the basis of this? This thought takes place, in my opinion, because it became possible to break the algorithm into steps and to speed up the process by simplifying at each step. What do you think?

```
c1 = Cylinder[{{0.5, 0, -1}, {0.5, 0, 1}}, 1/2] // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
R = c1;

(***Inertia Field***)
vars = {x, y, z};
r2 = IdentityMatrix[3] Tr[#] - # &@Outer[Times, vars, vars];
r2 // MatrixForm;

RegionMember[R, {x, y, z}];

Reduce[0 <= (1 + z)/2 <= 1 && (-(1/2) + x)^2 + y^2 <= 1/4, {x, y, 
    z}] // Expand;

Integrate[
  Integrate[
   Integrate[y^2 + z^2, {z, -1, 1}], {y, -Sqrt[x - x^2], Sqrt[
    x - x^2]}], {x, 0, 1}];
```

Comment: Please include the output of `$Version` to your post and also include the OS information that you are working with.

Comment: @Syed I added info

Comment: At least versions 12.2 to 13.2.1 succeed in performing this integration.

Comment: @kirma It's a pity. I tried to make a few more assumptions - it did not work.

Comment: For what it's worth, with `0.5` replaced with `1/2` and `FullSimplify[#, x >= 0] &` appled on the results, it is `Piecewise[{{(r*Sqrt[1 - r^2]*(19 + 2*r^2 + 16*r^4) + (8*I)*r^2*(4 + 3*r^2)*ArcCosh[r] + 19*(ArcCos[Sqrt[r]] - 2*ArcSin[Sqrt[1 + r]/Sqrt[2]] + 2*ArcTan[(1 + Sqrt[r])/Sqrt[1 - r]]))/48, r < 1}}, 0]`

Comment: This works in `12.0` try `Simplify[Integrate[y^2 + z^2, vars \[Element] R], 
 Assumptions -> {r > 0 && r < 1}]`

Comment: Also it seems that it works on 12.2 only if one has replaced `0.5` in the `Cylinder` definition with `1/2`. Probably worth a try. (I admit I rationalized those parts without thinking.)

Comment: @kirma ok, that also worked! also see my edit please

Comment: Regarding more efficient computational procedure... you could change integration variables, from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates. Either manually, or with `IntegrateChangeVariables`, but it's a feature added in v13.1. (It doesn't make symbolic calculation faster, but makes results more tolerable.)

Comment: @kirma thanks for the advice! I'll try to do something with it. You can also write your own answer if you feel like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
$Version
```

> [image: ver]

if we try

```
c1 = Cylinder[{{0.5, 0, -1}, {0.5, 0, 1}}, 1/2] // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
c2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, r] // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
R = RegionDifference[c1, c2];
Integrate[y^2 + z^2, vars ∈ R]
```

> [image: res]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The calculation time is satisfactory. But I'm afraid that this is not the end yet, because. more complex shapes may require a more complex procedure. I will accept your answer and would like to offer you the following idea: the calculation of such integrals can be reduced to triple integration with well-defined limits of integration. Using the `RegionMember` command, we will find conditions that tell us that a given set of parameters is in a given region. Then, using the `Reduce` command, we will solve the equations for the variables `x, y, z`.

Comment: This approach gave me the same result as the `MomentOfInertia` command for the whole region (however, I integrated over a regular cylinder). If we learn how to correctly extract the limits of integration and integrate, then something can come of it. See my edit, please.

Comment: @dtn I just saw that. sorry for the delayed response, busy day. Your idea is valid and in principle should work very nicely I think. I will try to have a look at your edit later, but cannot make any promises.

Comment: It's OK! Check it out when you have free time. I will continue to study the problem. Also see the interesting second answer in this topic.

Comment: @dtn I saw it very quickly and upvoted already :-)

Answer (score 5):

When working at this problem I found out that newer versions generate particularly complicated results, making `FullSimplify` never return a nice, simple answer. Performing the integration on cylindrical coordinates (after all, one of the regions involved *is* a cylinder oriented on the $z$ axis in the style of `"Cylindrical"` coordinates) helps on this problem:

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][
  y^2 + z^2,
  Element[{x, y, z},
   RegionDifference[
    Cylinder[{{1/2, 0, -1}, {1/2, 0, 1}}, 1/2],
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, r]]]],
 {rr, \[Theta], zz}, "Cartesian" -> "Cylindrical",
 Assumptions -> r >= 0]
```

[image]

```
Activate[%]
```

[image]

```
FullSimplify[%, 0 <= r <= 1]

(* 1/48 (r Sqrt[1 - r^2] (19 + 2 r^2 + 16 r^4) +
         (19 - 8 r^2 (4 + 3 r^2)) ArcCos[r]) *)
```

Note that `rr` and `zz` are used in coordinate conversion in order to avoid conflict with `r` and `z`.

Comment: Cool and very inspiring idea with the change of coordinates!